# Actionscript, load random Movie Clip into Scene

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

I'm making a simple flash shooting gallery animation with about 5 targets on screen but I am useless at action script.

I have the main scene and 5 Target movie clips in an array. I would like to...
-> Start Animation -> load random clip -> play random clip till end-> generate new random clip -> Repeat with Delay Offset....

So far I have the following:

```
function getRandomLabel():String {
var labels:Array = new Array("Tar1", "Tar2", "Tar3", "Tar4", "Tar5");

var index:Number = Math.floor(Math.random() * labels.length);
return labels[index];
}
this.gotoAndStop(getRandomLabel());
}
```

This is working... but I would like to add a delay and no repeat to this...

Comment: The specific **technical** problem you are having is unclear. Could be anything from *don't know how to play a MovieClip* to *don't know what algorithm is*.

Comment: please look again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, lets do it.

```
// If you need to avoid playing the same movie two times.
var lastLabel:*;

// The list of labels.
var Labels:Array = ["Tar1", "Tar2", "Tar3", "Tar4", "Tar5"];

function playRandom():*
{
    do
    {
        // Get a random index.
        var anIndex:int = Math.random() * Labels.length;
    }
    while (Labels[anIndex] == currentLabel);

    // Keep the current label in the variable.
    currentLabel = Labels[anIndex];
    gotoAndStop(currentlabel);
}

function playNext():void
{
    // 1000 milliseconds = 1 second delay.
    setInterval(playRandom, 1000);
}
```

Then. At the end of each of your movie clips you need to correctly call the **playNext** method. If these movies are in the same timeline, as the code above, just call **playNext();** If they are separate **MovieClip** objects, it will probably be **(parent as MovieClip).playNext();** I cannot really tell because I don't know the structure of your movie. You will probably need to read the following to understand: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7e3e.html

Comment: couldn't get this to work... probably down to my main scene design and labels but thank you for your help.... I have it sorted now...